# Mac terminal parameters or arguments to run app as 'admin' or without asking for permissions to folders

Tags: python, macos, permissions, entitlements

Can you run an app from terminal with parameters so the app doesn't ask you for permissions to access documents folder/desktop folder/pictures folder etc? I've made an app that detects storage usage on user
profiles and the users can just click no for the permissions which breaks the program. The app will be used to monitor and enforce company policies that the users will be prompted to acknowledge before signing in to the Lab computers so privacy isn't an issue.
[One of five permissions for the app that the user has to accept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esreL.png)

The app us Python based and was packaged with py2app but I know the code could be run through something like Jamf which might negate the need for permissions if that might work? I've tried adding an info.plist to the package to include these permissions and I've tried looking at alternative ways of detecting the storage usage. I've got not experience with Mac thus far.